# Hibernate one to one mapping. Schema generation issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I am generating schema with hibernate mapping. But for some reason by one to one mapping is not getting generated properly. Here are my classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "resturant")
public class Restaurant {

    private Integer restid;
    private String restaurantName;
    private Foursquare foursquare;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "restid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getId() {
        return restid;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.restid = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Foursquare getFoursquare() {
        return foursquare;
    }

    public void setFoursquare(Foursquare foursquare) {
        this.foursquare = foursquare;
    }

    @Column(name = "restname")
    public String getRestaurantName() {
        return restaurantName;
    }

    public void setRestaurantName(String restaurantName) {
        this.restaurantName = restaurantName;
    }

}
```

and,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foursquare")
public class Foursquare {

    private Integer foursquareid;
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "fsid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getFoursquareid() {
        return foursquareid;
    }

    public void setFoursquareid(Integer foursquareid) {
        this.foursquareid = foursquareid;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Restaurant getRestaurant() {
        return restaurant;
    }

    public void setRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
    }
}
```

My hbm file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- You need to complete the configuration here. This is just a sample, 
            you should use a connection pool -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/menus3</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping class="Restaurant" />
        <mapping class="Foursquare" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is my HibernateUtil class:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public final class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {

            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    private HibernateUtil() {

    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

I am running a simple class to generate the schema by just loading the configuration:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

This should create a foreign key of restid in Foursquare table but it does not. The sql looks like:

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists foursquare
Hibernate: drop table if exists resturant
Hibernate: create table foursquare (fsid integer not null auto_increment, idinfoursquare varchar(255), primary key (fsid))
Hibernate: create table resturant (restid integer not null auto_increment, restname varchar(255), staddress varchar(255), primary key (restid))
```

Can anyone point out why the one to one mapping is not getting reflected in my DB? Why the foreign key column is not getting generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`. The `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation does say that the primary key of the entity is used as the foreign key value to the associated entity. So foreign key is not getting generated. To generate foreign key you should remove `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotaion.

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn     Remove this annotation.
public Restaurant getRestaurant() {
    return restaurant;
}
```